# Why does Android: java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked error occur?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have created an activity with sms fetching from an android DB. When I run my app on a Lenovo A7010a48 (Android version: 5.1) an error occurs.
It is working fine on other phones and operating systems.

```
**AccessibilityManager﹕ setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
    java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
            at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)**


 D/AccessibilityManager﹕ setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
    java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
            at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)
            at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:636)
            at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.<init>(AccessibilityManager.java:226)
            at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:206)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9874)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4228)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:524)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:215)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:206)
            at android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout.<init>(FitWindowsLinearLayout.java:36)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:413)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
            at competent.groove.swalok.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6220)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: did you find the solution, I am facing the same problem?

Comment: no , i didn't find any solution

Comment: ok let me know if you do and if i find one i will let you know

Comment: I know it's extremely late but are you trying to refer context in onCreate or is any function called from onCreate trying to access Context ? In any case, can you please post your onCreate method ?

Comment: please share your full code.